# Toggle Data using RadioButton

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created one vf page with four radiobuttons Attachments,Files,Documents and StaticResource. If i click on File option it should show File related Data.

Now i am doing it Static,but it should dynamic

**VisualForce**

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="TestPageForRadioCtrl">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:selectRadio value="{!optionSelected}">
               <apex:selectoptions value="{!radioValues}"></apex:selectoptions>
            </apex:selectRadio>
            <apex:pageBlockSection Title="Different Radio">

                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!selectedObj}" var="s">
                    <apex:column value="{!s.id}"/>
                </apex:pageblockTable>



            </apex:pageBlockSection>     
        </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class**

```
public with sharing class TestPageForRadioCtrl {

public String optionSelected{get;set;}
public List<Sobject> selectedObj{get;set;}
public List<WrapperClass> wrap{get;set;}
Map <String,Schema.SobjectType> schemaMap=Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
public List<SelectOption> Name
{
    get{

      List<String> gd=new List<String>();
     List<SelectOption> options=new List<SelectOption>();  
     gd.addAll(schemaMap.keySet());
     Schema.DescribeSobjectResult[] results= Schema.describeSobjects(gd);

     for(Schema.DescribeSobjectResult res:results)
     {
         options.add(new SelectOption(res.getName(),res.getLabel()));
     }

     return options;   

    }

 }

public List<SelectOption> radioValues 
    {
        get {
        List<SelectOption> resList = new List<SelectOption>();
        resList.add(new SelectOption('Attachment', 'Attachment'));
        resList.add(new SelectOption('ContentDocument', 'Files'));
         resList.add(new SelectOption('Document', 'Document'));
          resList.add(new SelectOption('StaticResource', 'Static Resource'));
        return resList;
            }
    }


public TestPageForRadioCtrl(){

    optionSelected='ContentDocument';
    selectedObj=new List<Sobject>();
      if(optionSelected!=null||optionSelected!='')
      {
          Schema.sobjectType sobj=schemaMap.get(optionSelected);
          selectedObj=Database.query('Select id from '+sobj);
          optionSelected=String.valueof(sobj);
          system.debug('----Sobject----'+selectedObj);

      }

} 


public Class WrapperClass
{
    public String type{get;set;}
    public integer index{get;set;}
    public Boolean Selecetd{get;set;}
    public Sobject sobj{get;set;}


    public WrapperClass(String s,Sobject sob,Integer i,Boolean b)
    {
        type=s;
        sobj=sob;
        Index=i;
        Selecetd=b;

    }



}

}
```

Comment: You'll need to add an action method if you want the page to update when you change the radio button settings.